# CarouselView not displaying images when I bind the CarouselView object to an ImageSource

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been able to use CarouselView to display images by binding the CarouselView to an ObservableCollection of strings representing image URLs, and referencing those URLs directly with the Source property of the Image tag in XAML files:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="carouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding CarImages}">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                                <Image Source="{Binding FileName}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

This displays both the image and the filename as I'd like it to.

But now I am trying to create a CarouselView of images by binding the CarouselView to ImageSource objects instead of binding them to strings.  The ObservableCollection of ImageSource objects is defined in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> ImageSources { get; set; }
```

The ImageSource objects are created by passing the file paths into the ImageSource.FromFile method:

```
foreach(MediaFile photoFile in photoFiles)
            {
                CarViewModel.ImageSources.Add(ImageSource.FromFile(photoFile.Path));
            }
```

Now I try to display these in my xaml file:

```
                <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding ImageSources}" HeightRequest="500">
                    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                </CarouselView>
```

but the image is not displayed.

I am able to display one image at a time, though:

`CarViewModel.SampleImage.Source = CarViewModel.ImageSources[0];`

`<Image Source="{Binding SampleImage.Source}"/>`

This does display a single image.

Why is it that images are not being displayed by the CarouselView?

Edit: here is the entire ViewModel, as requested by Leo Zhu - MSFT

```
using MyProgram.Models;
using MyProgram.Views;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProgram.ViewModels
{
    public class CarDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        string name, description, priceString;
        DateTime date;
        public ObservableCollection<Photograph> CarImages { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> ImageSources { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public CarouselView carouselView;
        private ImageSource sampleImageSource;
        public ImageSource SampleImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return sampleImageSource;
            }
            set
            {
                sampleImageSource = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SampleImageSource");
            }
        }
        private Image sampleImage;
        public Image SampleImage
        {
            get 
            {
                return sampleImage;
            }
            set 
            { 
                sampleImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SampleImage");

            }
        }
        decimal price;
        Car car;

        public void AddImages(List<string> fileNames, bool areNewImages)
        {

            if (CarImages == null || CarImages.Count == 0)
                CarImages = new ObservableCollection<Photograph>();
            string pathToImages = Path.GetDirectoryName(Constants.ItemsDatabasePath) + "/images/";
            foreach (string fileName in fileNames)
            {
                string filenameInLoop = pathToImages + Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                Photograph carImage = new Photograph { FileName = filenameInLoop, IsNew = areNewImages };

                CarImages.Add(carImage);
                OnPropertyChanged("fileName");
                OnPropertyChanged("CarImages");
            }
        }
        public void RemoveImage(Photograph imageToRemove)
        {
            CarImages.Remove(imageToRemove);
            OnPropertyChanged("CarImages");
        }
        public DateTime Date
        {
            set
            {
                if (date != value)
                {
                    Car.Date = date = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Date");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return date;
            }
        }
        
        public string DatabasePath => Constants.ItemsDatabasePath;
        public string Name
        {
            set
            {
                if (name != value)
                {
                    Car.Name = name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
        }
        public string Description
        {
            set
            {
                if (description != value)
                {
                    Car.Description = description = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return description;
            }
        }
        public String PriceString
        {
            set
            {
                if (priceString != value)
                {
                    priceString = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PriceString");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return priceString;
            }
        }
        public decimal Price
        {
            set
            {
                if (price != value)
                {
                    Car.Price = price = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Price");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return price;
            }
        }
        
        public Car Car
        {
            set
            {
                if (car != value)
                {
                    car = new Car
                    {
                        Id = value.Id,
                        Name = value.Name,
                        Price = value.Price,
                        Description = value.Description,
                        Date = value.Date
                    };
                    OnPropertyChanged("Car");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Id");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Price");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                    OnPropertyChanged("ImageFile");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Date");

                }
            }
            get
            {
                return car;
            }
        }
        public CarDetailViewModel(Car car = null)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<UpdateCarPage, Car>(this, "UpdateCar", (obj, item) =>
            {
                Car = item;
            });
            if (car != null)
                Car = car;
            else
                Car = new Car();
            this.Name = Car.Name;
            this.Description = Car.Description;
            this.Price = Car.Price;
            this.Date = Car.Date;
            OnPropertyChanged("Date");
            OnPropertyChanged("Car");
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            OnPropertyChanged("Description");
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageFile");

        }
        public void ReloadCarFromDataStore()
        {
            string Id = Car.Id;
            car = App.CarRepository.GetItemAsync(Id).Result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your complete viewmodel ?

Comment: Leo Zhu, have added the entire viewmodel to the question.

Comment: I don't see the assignment to ImageSources in your viewmodel.